# DB fields not changing after updates

Tags: mysql, ruby

I'm learning some basic stuff in Sinatra with the MySQL gem. The website I'm trying to build is somewhat like www.facemash.com.au.

I give two pictures to the visitor and they vote for one. When they vote, a POST request is sent to the '/vote' path.

My current handler for this route is:

```
  post '/vote' do
    @db = Mysql.new(host, user, pass, DB_name)
    @old_winner_vote = @db.prepare "SELECT wins FROM accounts WHERE id = ? "
    @winner_vote = @old_winner_vote.execute params[:winer]
    @winner_votes = @winner_vote.fetch.to_s.to_i
    @winner_votes += 1
    @update_winner_vote = @db.prepare "UPDATE accounts SET wins = ? WHERE id = ? "
    @update_winner_vote.execute @winner_votes, params[:winer]
    @old_looser_vote = @db.prepare "SELECT looses FROM accounts WHERE id = ? "
    @looser_vote = @old_looser_vote.execute params[:looser]
    @looser_votes = @looser_vote.fetch.to_s.to_i
    @looser_votes += 1
    @update_looser_vote = @db.prepare "UPDATE accounts SET looses = ? WHERE id = ? "
    @update_looser_vote.execute @looser_votes, params[:looser]
    @db.close
    redirect '/', 303
  end
```

It looks like something is going wrong somewhere, because the `wins`/`looses` never go higher than 1. I tried to reset them to 0 and they updated from 0 to 1, but never higher.

Also I tried to set them to higher numbers from the MySQL console, and they were updated successfully, but when my Sinatra application tries to update them they reset to 1.

The `wins`/`looses` in MySQL DB is defined as follows:

```
| wins     | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| looses   | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Any idea what's wrong and how to fix it?

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 14.04 x64bit
- ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
- sinatra 1.4.5
- mysql 2.9.1
- thin 1.6.3

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you ask a question, it really helps us answer it if you use something more descriptive than "what's wrong with my code?" What are you trying to accomplish? Why can't you? Summarize those into a single short sentence. Also, putting the tags into the title doesn't help because we use the tags you supply to search, not the title. Leave that space for the summary.

Comment: What does the incoming POST request's data look like? We need the field names and values.

Comment: incoming POST is something like:
POST /vote?winer=winner_id_here&looser=looser_id_here
in simple description, I want this code to increment the wins# of winner by 1 and same for looser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in

```
@winner_vote = @old_winner_vote.execute params[:winer]
@winner_votes = @winner_vote.fetch.to_s.to_i
```

When calling @winner_vote.fetch it returns this: [#]  then calling .to_s turns it into "[#]" so calling .to_i will give 0 always thus calling +1 will give 1, at second call it'll go in the same way getting "[1]" as the string and 0 as the integer incrementing will give 1, that's why it never went higher than 1.
This can be fixed like this:

```
@winner_votes = @winner_vote.fetch.to_s[1...-1].to_i
```

This way calling .to_s[1..-1] will remove the [ ] leaving only the number inside, then it'll increment the number by 1 and update the database successfully.
same fix apply to @looser_votes

```
@looser_votes = @looser_vote.fetch.to_s[1...-1].to_i
```